# Не работает код для игры в слова

Tags: python, pycharm

Неделю назад смастерил этот код на питоне. Все работало на отлично. Сегодня же запустил PyCharm, заранил код, а он не работает. Проблема в том, что input требует ввести значение и сколько раз ты не нажимал бы enter, input его не принимает.
Вот код

```
input('нажмите ENTER, чтобы продолжить')
first_repeat_error = 0
second_repeat_error = 0
word_bank = []
print("""
Правила:
Слова должны состоять как минимум из двух букв.
Первое слово может быть любым.
Если начало вашего слова не совпадает с концом слова оппонента, то вы проиграли.
Одно и тоже слово можно повторить только один раз.
""")

while True:
    first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
    while len(first_gamer_word) <= 1:
        print("Слова состоят как минимум из двух букв")
        first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
        continue
    while True:
        if first_gamer_word.isalpha():
            pass
        else:
            print("Вводите только слова, НЕ цифры, пробелы и прочее")
            first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
            continue
    second_gamer_word = input("Второй игрок\n")
    while len(second_gamer_word) <= 1:
        print("Слова состоят как минимум из двух букв")
        second_gamer_word = input("Второй игрок\n")
        continue
    while True:
        if second_gamer_word.isalpha():
            pass
        else:
            print("Вводите только слова НЕ цифры, пробелы и прочее")
            second_gamer_word = input("Второй игрок\n")
            continue
    word_bank.append(first_gamer_word.capitalize())
    word_bank.append(second_gamer_word.capitalize())
    if second_gamer_word.lower()[0] != first_gamer_word.lower()[-1]:
        print("Второй игрок проиграл")

    while True:
        first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
        while len(first_gamer_word) <= 1:
            print("Слова состоят как минимум из двух букв")
            first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
            continue
        second_gamer_word = word_bank[-1]
        if first_repeat_error <= 1:
            if first_gamer_word in word_bank:
                first_repeat_error = first_repeat_error + 1
            word_bank.append(second_gamer_word.capitalize())
        if first_repeat_error == 1:
            print("Первый игрок проиграл\nПричина: Это слово уже использовали")
            break
        if second_gamer_word.lower()[-1] != first_gamer_word.lower()[0]:
            print("Первый игрок проиграл")
            break
        second_gamer_word = input("Второй игрок\n")
        while len(second_gamer_word) <= 1:
            print("Слова состоят как минимум из двух букв")
            second_gamer_word = input("Второй игрок\n")
            continue
        if second_repeat_error <= 1:
            if second_gamer_word in word_bank:
                second_repeat_error = second_repeat_error + 1
            word_bank.append(second_gamer_word.capitalize())
        if second_repeat_error == 1:
            print("Второй игрок проиграл\nПричина: Это слово уже использовали")
            break
        if first_gamer_word.lower()[-1] != second_gamer_word.lower()[0]:
            print("Второй игрок проиграл")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот такие циклы у вас бесконечные для обоих игроков:

```
while True:
    if first_gamer_word.isalpha():
        pass
    else:
        print("Вводите только слова, НЕ цифры, пробелы и прочее")
        first_gamer_word = input("Первый игрок\n")
        continue
```

Там нужен `break`, а не `pass`:

- `break` - прерывает цикл
- `pass` - это команда-заглушка, она не делает ничего и применяется там, где по синтаксису языка `Python` надо что-то написать (иначе будет синтаксическая ошибка), но вы пока не хотите ничего конкретного там писать